# MongoDB. Проверить существует ли объект в БД. Если нет, то добавить, если да, то пройти мимо

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Посылаю GET запрос каждые 10 секунд и записываю данные в массив объектов и этот массив кладу в базу.
Необходимо сделать проверку на существования объекта в БД по айдишнику, который получаю с сервера, и если его нет, то добавить, если такой объект уже есть в базе, то пройти мимо.

Таким образом:

```
"use strict";

// const dbUrl = "mongodb://localhost:27017/prozorro-test";
const mongoose = require("libs/mongoose");

let tender = new mongoose.Schema({
    tenderId: String,
    tenderDate: String
});

let Tenders = mongoose.model("Tenders", tender);


const request = require("request");

let offset = new Date().toISOString();
let url = `http://public.api.openprocurement.org/api/2.4/tenders?offset=${offset}+02.00`;

function getTenders(time) {
    time = new Date().toISOString();
    url = `http://public.api.openprocurement.org/api/2.4/tenders?offset=${time}+02.00`; // offset - время сохранения данных на сервере, у меня оно меняется каждые 10 секунд
    request(url, {json: true}, (err, res, body) => {
        if (err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }

        let tendersList = []; // создаю массив объектов
        body.data.forEach(function (item) {
            let tendersData = new Tenders({
                tenderId: item.id,
                tenderDate: item.dateModified
            }); // кладу данные полученные с сервера в объекты
            tendersList.push(tendersData); // сохраняю полученные объекты в массив объектов
            Tenders.insertMany(tendersList) // сохраняю массив объектов в бд
                .then(item => {
                    console.log("Saved to db")
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    throw new Error;
                });
            // console.log(`Tender id:${item.id}`);
            // console.log(`Tender data:${item.dateModified}`);
        });
    });
}

getTenders();
setInterval(getTenders, 10000);
```

Подскажите, как это дело осуществить, т.к с такой реализацией добавляется по одному объекту.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

извиняюсь, я с трудом понимаю ваш код, но кажется понимаю проблему. если у вас получается есть массив объектов, и вы хотите записать в бд только те, которые в бд  отсутсвую, и записать в одну операцию (балк), то можно сначала отфильтровать массив объектов по отсуствию в бд и далеезаписать в бд

```
// фильтруем
const allIds = body.data.map(item => item.id);
const existingRecords = await Tenders.find({ tenderId: { $in: allIds } }, 'tenderId');
const existingIds = existingRecords.map(r => r.tenderId);
const missingItems = body.data.filter(item => !existingIds.includes(item.id));

// пишем
const result = await Tenders.collection.insert(missingItems.map(item => ({
    tenderId: item.id,
    tenderDate: item.dateModified
})));
```

**Однако**, судя по наличию поля `dateModified` было бы правильние по нему и работать не мой взгляд, хотя возможно я не прав не зная конкретики

Comment: что именно не понятно? давайте я исправлю или объясню как я понимаю )) я не спорю, код сырой, писал за пару часов, я просто хочу действительно разобраться, а не просто решить проблему.
лучше по айдишнику, а не по дате, так как по дате может быть несколько вхождений, а айди все же уникальный.

Comment: мне кажется await работать не будет, если функция не асинхронная

Comment: await для упрощения примера.. можно добавить async перед функцией и будет работать, можно промисами написать.. ну сообщайте, если не получится, удачи

Comment: я прошу прощения, подскажите плз, делая так, как вы говорите я получаю две ошибки: первая - метод includes() - includes is not a function. я заменил запись на body.data.filter(item => item.id in existingIds) . и после запуска всего дела получаю MongoError: Invalid Operation, no operations specified.

Comment: может быть действительно вопрос не корректно задал..
суть в том, что я беру данные с гет запроса, пишу их в массив объектов, затем этот массив объектов сохраняю в бд. этот запрос я повторяю каждые 10 секунд. рано или поздно данные обновятся, так вот я хочу, чтоб каждый раз когда что-то пришло с гет запроса, оно не сохранялось в бд( будет дублирование ), а проверялось есть ли такие данные в базе, если их нет, то сохранить, если нет, то пройти мимо

Comment: приветствую! includes чтобы работал я думаю надо в бабеле добавить stage-1 или env или какой-то из них (надо погуглить)!  ну а дальше надо дебажить, поставить брейкпоинты и смотреть.  allIds должен быть массивом, existingIds тоже массивом и т.д. !

Comment: могу объяснить как решить проблему https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71676/

Comment: точнее вот https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71680/room-for-daniel-khoroshko-and-andrei

Answer (score 1):

```
tendersList.forEach(tender => {
Tenders.updateOne(           
        {tenderId:tender.tenderId},
        {$setOnInsert:tender},
        {upsert:true})
})
```

Comment: но это обновит объект в любом случае, а в задаче написано "есть есть, то обойти мимо"

Comment: и если не добавить в конце `overwrite: true` тогда мангуст не будет обновлять поля, в том случае, если они были удалены

Comment: @DanielKhoroshko не обновит... $setOnInsert сработает только на добавление нового...

Comment: я имею в виду что если был такой объект `{ val1: 1, val2: 2 }`, а стал таким `{ val1: 3 }`, то в базе мы получим в результате этой операции следующий объект `{ val1: 3, val2: 2 }`, если не добавить overwrite: true в последний аргумент, так как мангус по умолчанию проводит update операции как $set по имеющимся полям в аргументе апдейта. К сожалению, я всё равно не понял что хотел спросить автор вопроса, так что возможно в итоге вы правы!

Comment: @DanielKhoroshko узнаем у автора..)))

Comment: @DanielKhoroshko, имелось в виду, что уже какие-то данные добавлены в базу в ходе гет запроса, потом через 10 секунд отправляется еще один гет запрос по тому же пути, там информация обновляется, и нужно добавить новые объекты в бд, но старые при этом не трогать

Comment: проверить есть ли объект в базе можно запросив findOne() или findById(), которые вернул null , если такого объекта не существует. Это помогает? :)

Comment: @DanielKhoroshko, вот я попробовал, сейчас отредактирую вопрос. но не получается реализовать добавление сразу много объектов, добавляется по одному, это тяжеловесная операция.

Comment: это не работает, проверил на руками созданных объектах

Answer (score 1):

В mongoose есть такая штука как Sсhema. В ней есть возможность пометить поле как уникальное, например:

```
let tender = new mongoose.Schema({
    tenderId: {
      type: String,
      unique:true // tenderId уникальное поле
   {
    tenderDate: String
});
```

По уникальному полю MongoDB сделает индекс. В MongoDB дубликатов уникальных полей быть не может. Соответственно, придумйте поле (или несколько) по которому можно идентифицировать обьект, сделайте его уникальным, и дубликаты писаться в БД не будут. Плюс у вас будет быстрый поиск по этим полям, поскольку они проиндекированны.